# how to add multiple link in a cell with phpExcel

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, phpexcel

I have a cell with multiple Link

```
+---------+---------+
|         |         |
| Cell 1  | Cell 2  |
|         |         |
+---------+---------+
|         | Link 1  |
|  ROW 1  | Link 2  |
|         | Link 3  |
+---------+---------+
```

how can I make this with phpExcel ?
I know below code can set hyperlink to a cell but i don't know how can set **multiple** link to a cell!

```
$objPHPExcelExport->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValue('A'.$index, $row)
                    ->setCellValue('B'.$index, $link);
$objPHPExcelExport->getActiveSheet()
                    ->getCell('B'.$index)
                    ->getHyperlink()
                    ->setUrl('http://'.$url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware that you can.... how would you do it in MS Excel? As far as I know, MS Excel allows a single link for the cell, not links for indivdual text blocks within that cell.

Even using MS Excel's HYPERLINK() function, and creating a concatenated string combining all the links

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.co.uk","GOOGLE")&CHAR(10)&HYPERLINK("http://www.amazon.co.uk","AMAZON")
```

doesn't achieve your objective.

---

So I don't beleive that what you want to do can be achieved in MS Excel; an if MS Exel doesn't allow it, then nor will PHPEexcel